# How do I remove Firefox extensions from my sync account?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-sync

I have installed a fresh version of Firefox several times and when the sync process was complete, I removed extensions that I no longer use. I was thinking the removals would sync to my account and that they may be removed from my other system or at a minimum not install on new Firefox installs kind of like the bookmarks do, but every time they keep coming back. Any ideas on how I can dissociate them from my account?